# Do transactions to subaddresses look different on the blockchain?

Tags: privacy, transaction-data, sub-address

If I sent from wallet A to wallet B's main address, then from wallet A to wallet B's subaddress, beyond normal "differences" in Monero transactions that obfuscate them, would the second transaction look different on the blockchain? (i.e. can you tell it went to a subaddress?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no discernible difference on the blockchain when paying to a subaddress or normal address.